# how can i get de xxx th last cell of a row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

How can I get with **plain javascript** (no Jquery) get the 4th or 5th or 6th cell of a row?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
        <td>cell 5</td>
        <td>cell 6</td>
        <td>cell 7</td>
        <td>cell 8</td>
        <td>cell 9</td>
        <td>cell 10</td>
        <td>cell 11</td>
        <td id="lastcell2">cell 12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have created a bad jquery function, as example. I need a function like:

```
function getLastRowCell(row, number) {

//in wrong jquery: 
if (number == 1) {
  return $('#lastcell' + row).prev();
} else if (number == 2) {
  return $('#lastcell' + row).prev().prev();
} else {
  ... etc ...
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

1. arrays and collections in JS are 0 based
2. You can get ALL cells of the table using querySelectorAll

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td");
const getCell = cell => cells[cell-1];

const cell4 = getCell(4)
cell4.classList.add("selected")
console.log(cell4.textContent)
```

```css
.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
    <td>cell 9</td>
    <td>cell 10</td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to get cell y of row x you can do

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr");
const getRowCell = (row,cell) => rows[row-1].cells[cell-1];

const row2Cell4 = getRowCell(2,4);
row2Cell4.classList.add("selected");
console.log(row2Cell4.textContent);
```

```css
.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 2</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 3</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 4</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 5</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 6</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 7</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 8</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 9</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 10</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 11</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 2</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 3</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 4</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 5</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 6</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 7</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 8</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 9</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 10</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 11</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you get all cells in an array and can be accessed by the index.

```js
let tr = document.querySelector("tr");
let td = tr.querySelectorAll("td");

console.log(td[3].innerHTML);
console.log(td[4].innerHTML);
console.log(td[5].innerHTML);
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
        <td>cell 5</td>
        <td>cell 6</td>
        <td>cell 7</td>
        <td>cell 8</td>
        <td>cell 9</td>
        <td>cell 10</td>
        <td>cell 11</td>
        <td id="lastcell2">cell 12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```